# What is the right way to calculate sub-sequence, subset and sub-strings?

Tags: algorithm

Often, I come across the following terminology in coding interviews.

Given an array or string, find the
sub-array
sub-sequence
sub-string

What difference they have?
For example, I see an integer array can be split into

> n*(n+1)/2

sub arrays. Do they become subsets as well? Should sub-arrays are contiguous? 
For calculating the sub-sequences of a string, why to use

> 2^str_length - 1

After searching online, I ended up with this link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/

But I still feel ambiguous as what is the universal term for calling a part of an array/string? and how to compute them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  **2^n - 1** is the quantity of proper subsets of a given set.  **n*(n-1)/2** is the quantity of un-ordered pairs from a set; I'm not sure how it relates to your problems, nor how the **(n+1)** term relates..  Perhaps give some concrete examples to illustrate your problems?

Comment: @Prune Sorry, if my question was incomplete. Now I edited it with more details.

Comment: You go to programming job interviews without knowing what an array is?! You're wasting your time, complete a computer science educational course first.

Comment: If you can't comment anything useful, better stay away. Being polite is more important. There are more novice questions in stack overflow which were answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, arrays and strings are both sub-sequences.  The "sequence" part indicates that the order of elements is important somehow.  "substring" is usually contiguous; "sub-array" and "sub-sequence" are unclear.  If you're in a job interview and not certain of the interpretation, your first job is to ask.  Sometimes, part of the job interview is making sure you can spot and resolve ambiguities.

---

**UPDATE after question update**

I find the referenced page quite clear.
First, note that *string* and *array* are both specific types of a *sequence*.

- **subsequence** is the generic term: elements of the original sequence
  appearing in the same order as in the original, but not necessarily contiguous.  For instance, given the sequence "abcdefg", we have sub-sequences "a", "ag", bce", etc.
- Elements repeated or otherwise not in the original ordering would include "ga", "bb", bcfe", etc.  None of these is a sub-sequence.
- "Subset" is a separate type.  In a set, repeated elements do not exist, and ordering does not matter.

Does that clear up your problems?

Comment: Thanks Prune. As you pointed out, points 2 and 3 were my questions. Should there be repetition or not? or what about the ordering? Should we have the original ordering? 
will this be a valid sub-sequence? "bce", "cdg"?